# Reading strings send from C# with arduino

Tags: c#, asp.net, c

would appreciate any help am still learning C# and arduino communication.. am trying to receive some data on arduino send from C# but am failing to see the send data on serial monitor. i would want to know how i receive the send data. below are my codes:

C#:

```css
protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                try
                {
                    comPort.Open();
                    comPort.Write(TextBox1.Text);
                    comPort.Write("Delete");
                    comPort.Close();
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
                }
                try
                {
                    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\Stock.mdb"));
                    conn.Open();
                   Int32 ash = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
                    string deleteQuery = "delete from Instock where ID= '" + ash + "'";
                    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(deleteQuery, conn);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Write("Item deleted successfully");
                    Response.Redirect("UpdateDB.aspx");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Arduino:

```html
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial xbee(2, 3);
int incoming;
int id;
int rea;
int comp=0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  xbee.begin( 9600 );
 }

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available())
   {
     Serial.print("hhhh");
     id = Serial.read();
     incoming = Serial.read();
     if(id!='New')
     {
     xbee.println(id);
     xbee.println(incoming);
     EEPROM.write(id, incoming);
     rea = EEPROM.read(id);
     Serial.print(id);
    }
    else
     {
      EEPROM.write(comp, incoming);
      rea = EEPROM.read(id);
      Serial.print(id);
      comp+=1;
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it is very important to define a message format that is flexible and suits your requirements of communication (e.g. sending/receiving commands with multiple arguments with different data types, etc.).

Fortunately, there is already a comprehensive library, called [CmdMessenger](https://github.com/thijse/Arduino-Libraries/tree/master/CmdMessenger), that handles the bidirectional communication between Arduino and a C# application. The use of the library is very simple and there are several [examples](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/CmdMessenger) available on the web. I think it is easily possible to change the examples for your individual needs.